cmake: possible to build a subproject library during config OR have a subdirectory of executables that wait to build until library is built
I have a large project that is being converted from autotools to cmake. There is collection of libraries that the rest of the code base depends on.  However, part of the project is destined to be separated out into stand alone repos.  This is causing difficulty with referencing the libs, as I cannot use their target names directly, instead using find_library or package search, etc... to locate them.
Given the following project layout, what would be the best way to get cmake to build the libraries first to allow the sub projects to find them?
main
  |- CMakeLists.txt (top)
  |- myLibs/
  |----CMakeLists.txt (currently only does add_subdirectory(libX)
  |----lib (outputdir from make install)
  |----include (public header output dir from make install)
  |----mylibA  
  |-------CMakeLists.txt  
  |----mylibB
  |-------CMakeLists.txt
  |-projCollections/ ( collection of programs )
  |----CMakeLists.txt (Depends on mylibA and mylibB)
  |----projA  -> Cannot reference any of myLibs directly
  |------CMakeLists.txt (Depends on mylibA )
  |----projb
  |------CMakeLists.txt (Depends on mylibA  and mylibB)

I currently only see a few solutions:

using execute_process to immediately run a cmake configure and make command on the myLibs

using ExternalProject_add on projCollections

using ExternalProject on myLibs.


ExternalProject seems plausible, but maybe I just need to allow the referencing for now and once the separation of sources occurs, go back through and update all (100+) CMakeLists.txt files to change back to find_library...
(basic current cmake structure...)
Top Level:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(main)
add_subdirectory(myLibs)
add_subdirectory(projCollections)

myLibs:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(myLibs DESCRIPTION "myLibs")
add_subdirectory(mylibA)
add_subdirectory(mylibB)

projCollections:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(projCollections DESCRIPTION "projCollections")
add_subdirectory(projA)
add_subdirectory(projB)

projA:
project(projA )
find_library(MYLIBA NAMES mylibA HINTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/myLibs/libs/mylibA.so NO_DEFAULT_PATH)    
add_executable(projA)
target_link_libraries(projA myLibA)


100+ CMakeLists.txt files seems excessive.

@AndréLehto  The subproject(s) under projCollections are all essentially "unique" projects that are distinct, but use libraries from the main project.  These are also getting moved out of the main repo into standalone projects in the future, so each project has it's own independent CMakeLists.

And there are 100+ subprojects? Anyhow, see my answer below, FetchContent is probably what you are looking for in any case. If it is, please give it an upvote and mark it as the solution.

@AndréLehto pretty much.   Old project that has grown over the years.

What you are looking for is FetchContent. Separate your project into separate repos as you planned, and then fetch them using FetchContent. They will then get built and be available to your project at build time. Here is a small example:
I have uploaded a very small library project to my GitHub called workbench. Inside are these files:
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.0)

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

project(workbench VERSION 1.0.0)

# Using INTERFACE for header only library
add_library(workbench INTERFACE)

# Giving scope to files inside library
target_include_directories(workbench INTERFACE $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>)

module.h
#include <string>

static std::string RandomVariable = "Hello from module";

From here, I've created a small project in which I include my workbench library. It looks as follows:
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.0)

project(tester VERSION 1.0.0)

# Allows us to use FetchContent
include(FetchContent)

# Fetches the repository from GitHub
FetchContent_Declare(workbench
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/andrelehto/workbench.git
    GIT_TAG v1.0.0
)

# Makes the repository available to us
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(workbench)

add_executable(tester main.cpp)

# Link to library from GitHub
target_link_libraries(tester workbench)

main.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "module.h"

int main() {
  std::cout << RandomVariable << std::endl;
}

Notice that module.h is now available to us in our main project.

I'll look at this.   I'll have see what the effects will be in our Jenkins system also.

so I have looked into fetchcontent, but it does not seem to do what I need.
I cannot see how to get the library project to build prior to the calls to add_subdirectory for the executables that depend on these libraries, which used find_library to search for the package.  I cannot use the fetchContent target name in those subdirectories as mentioned above.  If I could get the myLib library project to build first, then it would be ok.

Of course you can use the target name from FetchContent, that is the entire point... You have to call FetchContent_MakeAvailable and then the build target is available in your entire project (given that this is made on the top-level CMakeLists.txt). The library is also built before your own project, you can physically find them under the _deps directory inside your build directory.

I have fetchContent_Declare(mylibs......)  and then FetchContent_MakeAvailable(mylibs)  in the top level CMakeLists.txt
mylibs is a directory containing LibA...libN libraries.
`FetchContent_Declare(mylib
SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mylib
SUBBUILD_DIR mylib/build
BINARY_DIR mylib/build
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(mylib)
add_subdirectory(projA)`
in projA, I have: find_library(.... libA path/etc...) which should find the pre-built lib from FetchContent
Libs under mylibs are configured but not being built.
I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something...

Yes, you are. You are mixing a lot of different functionality that does not work like you think it does. find_library for example, expects a cmake config file, which is quite complicated and completely unecessary in your case. Please look at my example and read through the documentation.
